# Stored Procedure Snowflake with IF statement Null Check

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I edited the previous code to make it simpler.  Below returns to me always SELECT 2. I expect to have it SELECT 1 because etlId is 0.

Where could the problem be?

Thanks

Regards

```
'
function getScalarValue(queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd = {sqlText: "set etl_id = 0 "};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
    return out;
}
  var etlId = getScalarValue("select $etl_id");
        if (etlId == 0 )  
                {
                    var sql_command = "SELECT 1";
                }
        else {
                    var sql_command = "SELECT 2";
                  }
            try {
            snowflake.execute (
                {sqlText: sql_command}
                );
            return "Success" ;   // Return a success/error indicator.
            }
        catch (err)  {
            return "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
            }                   
'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. I have another solution to use a variable as a parameter at the script. When I call the procedure, I can use SQL to define the parameter so this works for me. Once again thank you very much for your help.

Regards

```
       create or replace procedure TEST(etlId, float)
        returns string
        language javascript
        execute as caller
        as
        $$
                if (etlId == 0 )  
                        {
                            var sql_command = "SELECT 1";
                        }
                else {
                            var sql_command = "SELECT 2";
                          }
                    try {
                    snowflake.execute (
                        {sqlText: sql_command}
                        );
                    return "Success" ;   // Return a success/error indicator.
                    }
                catch (err)  {
                    return "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
                    }  
      $$
    
call TEST (select count(etl_id) etlId from view where etl_id not in (select etl_id from table))
```

Answer (score 2):

`$etl_id` is not a JavaScript variable. It is a SQL variable. You can use a helper function get scalar values from a SQL statement. This helper function gets the first column, first row value and returns it:

Update: Based on your updates, it's more like this:

```
create or replace procedure TEST()
returns string
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$

  var etlId = getScalarValue("select $etl_id");
        if (etlId == 0 )  
                {
                    var sql_command = "SELECT 1";
                }
        else {
                    var sql_command = "SELECT 2";
                  }
            try {
            snowflake.execute (
                {sqlText: sql_command}
                );
            return "Success" ;   // Return a success/error indicator.
            }
        catch (err)  {
            return "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
            }  
            
function getScalarValue(queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
    return out;
}

$$;

set etl_id = 1;
call test();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly reply. The thing is that it sets the variable three times in a row. What could it be the reason?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a similar issue. It jumps to else case and does only SELECT 1 instead of create or replace table. 
I did select count (*) for the variable. If the result is >0 then it will create the table else select 1. I have tested and no matter if it is equal to zero or not it does only select 1.

Comment: I just noticed that your input parameter name is "$elt_id". That won't actually pass in a SQL variable. It will create a JavaScript variable with the same name, which will get confusing. It appears that you're trying to run a block of code depending on whether or not the ELT_ID parameter appears in a view. If that's the case, you can use a bind variable or replace it in the body of the SQL that's checking for its existence.

Comment: Hi Greg, I have just updated the code with your suggestion to make it clearer and understand better what the code does exactly. I am wondering why this variable doesn't work as we expected. Even if I assign it 0 it doesn’t return the first sql statement. Would you like to help with this please?